# iPhoto 7 - upgrade to Snow Leopard -> no video playback

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, iphoto

iPhoto 7.1.5 - working faithfully in 10.4 and 10.5, suddenly has forgotten how to play video after an upgrade to 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Apple's solution [for iPhoto 08 is to install a newer version of Quicktime](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3003), but on my system this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Removing com.apple.iPhoto.plist (in /Users/~/Library/Preferences), seems to have solved the problem.

Credit to the post by "Old Toad" -> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2796168?start=0&tstart=0

Is there any public registry of the values? When I took a diff of the new and old values, I did not see anything obvious that was reset that would cripple video playback> (I assumed it was a stale preference or a new, bogus default value.)